# Comsol Multiphysics Research Papers

Tags: simulation, reproducible-research, comsol

I am currently attempting to model the absorption of Carbon Dioxide by different solutions. I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325651154_Modeling_of_CO2_Capture_from_Gas_Stream_Emissions_of_Petrochemical_Industries_by_Membrane_Contactor) paper that does this. They used Comsol Multiphysics but show almost no images of them modeling things in Comsol. They only show the differential equations used.

Did they find these equations from scratch and input them into Comsol or did they just use the modeler and the physics?

How would I go about figuring out the procedure they did the experiment in if they did use the model builder and the physics plugins?

Comment: You ask several questions. Did they find these equations from scratch? Section "2.1. Governing equations" lists 5+ references where equations come from. "The obtained differential equation set is discretize by finite element method (FEM) and is solved
by UMEPACK solver of the COMSOL Multiphysics" (--> UMFPACK?!).

Comment: Experiment and Comsol Analysis are two different things. For both, there are probably several parameters and procedures which can probably NOT completely be derived from the paper.